# Android layout touch issue

Tags: java, android

I am building a test lock screen app. I have the design working, and it works, but wherever you press, it registers as it is at the number 1 position, and then makes the design relative to that. Here is the main design:

[image: main image]

Now If I click on the first position, it registers one, if I drag to 2 or 3, etc. it registers those numbers in the order that I drag. But If I want to start at position 2, it still registers as position 1 and so everything "shifts positon" (not the design, only the points of the rectangle).

How can I fix this? I am getting this, wherever I click (say I click position 2):

[image: position 1 being displayed]

But I need this:

[image]

here is my Java Code that makes the rectangles and when they are touched:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus){
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);       
        b1R = new Rect(b1.getLeft(), b1.getTop(), b1.getRight(), b1.getBottom());
        b2R = new Rect(b2.getLeft(), b2.getTop(), b2.getRight(), b2.getBottom());
        b3R = new Rect(b3.getLeft(), b3.getTop(), b3.getRight(), b3.getBottom());
        b4R = new Rect(b4.getLeft(), b4.getTop()+120, b4.getRight(), b4.getBottom()+120);
        b5R = new Rect(b5.getLeft(), b5.getTop()+120, b5.getRight(), b5.getBottom()+120);
        b6R = new Rect(b6.getLeft(), b6.getTop()+120, b6.getRight(), b6.getBottom()+120);
        b7R = new Rect(b7.getLeft(), b7.getTop()+240, b7.getRight(), b7.getBottom()+240);
        b8R = new Rect(b8.getLeft(), b8.getTop()+240, b8.getRight(), b8.getBottom()+240);
        b9R = new Rect(b9.getLeft(), b9.getTop()+240, b9.getRight(), b9.getBottom()+240);

}
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    x = (int) arg1.getX();
    y = (int) arg1.getY();

    if(b1R.contains(x, y)){
        arr.add("1");
        Log.d("block", "1");
    }
    if(b4R.contains(x,y)){
        arr.add("4");
        Log.d("block", "4");
    }
    if(b7R.contains(x,y)){
        arr.add("7");
        Log.d("block", "7");
    }

    if(b2R.contains(x,y)){
        arr.add("2");
        Log.d("block", "2");
    }
    if(b8R.contains(x,y)){
        arr.add("8");
        Log.d("block", "8");
    }
    if(b5R.contains(x,y)){
        arr.add("5");
        Log.d("block", "5");
    }

    if(b3R.contains(x,y)){
        arr.add("3");
        Log.d("block", "3");
    }
    if(b6R.contains(x,y)){
        arr.add("6");
        Log.d("block", "6");
    }
    if(b9R.contains(x,y)){
        arr.add("9");
        Log.d("block", "9");
    }

    return false;
}
```

The reason the `bXr.contains`is in that order is because if it was `0-9` order, it would not register correctly, it would freak out and register 1, 2 and 3 (then 4, 5 and 6, and then 7, 8 and 9) all in the same block for some reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: Firstly i would recommend placing those RECT objects into an array or arrayList and then using a for(Rect r : rectList) loop to test the contains condition. The rectangle number you add to arr can simply be its position in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what exacly you use, but I bet you have nine (Image)Views in a Layout and registered all their touchevents to one listener. The effect you describe would happen if you do so, because touch events are in the subcoordinate system of the touched view.

You can lay a transparent View above everything and use the touch events arriving there. Then it would work. Or you draw everything in one view.

Comment: I am using ImageButtons for this, is that wrong? also, I do not understand what you mean and how it would work by using a transparent view, or draw everything in one view